# subscriber over ip

Tags: ros, rviz, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a low speed cpu connected to a hokuyo laser. I would like to see its output on rviz. An example launch code is provided on ROS https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/laser_drivers/trunk/hokuyo_node/hokuyo_test.launch

However, since rviz and other GUI tools require some good amount of memory, I need to find a way to see the output on my laptop. Is there any way that I could send the hokuyo data over the ethernet?...so that I can view the data on an rviz running on my laptop?
Could I write any subscriber that listens to a node name on a particular ip? Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9363/subscriber-over-ip/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run only the hokuyo node on your 'limited' CPU and have it connected with setting [your environment variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) correctly (look at ROS_IP, ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME). Then you can run a roscore on your laptop and visualise all data with rviz. The communication will be handles for you over the published [ROS topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts) as a [sensor_msgs laserscan msg](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html).
You want to export the ROS_IP of your limited CPU on that CPU and also export the ROS_MASTER_URI to http://<your_laptop_ip_or_hostname>:11311

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3